# How to get the objects/arrays at runtime in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Consider the below two scenarios

**Scenario 1:**

```
function Unpack(response) {
    var employees = response.data[0].Employees;
    var departments = response.data[0].Departments;   
    return [employees, departments];
}
```

**Scenario 2:**

```
function Unpack(response) {
    var marketing = response.data[0].Marketings;
    var finances = response.data[0].Finances;
    var inventories = response.data[0].Inventories;
    return [marketing, finances, inventories];
}
```

So I mean to say that,I need to know before hand the arrays in the "response" object  and then to get the individual arrays from it and return it as individual arrays?

Is there any generic way of doing so...say by using reflection or something of that sort in JavaScript way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass a list of properties as second argument?

```
function unpack(data, props) {
    var result = [];
    props.forEach(function(prop) {
        result.push(data[prop]);
    });
    return result;
}

unpack(response.data[0], ['Employees', 'Departments']);
unpack(response.data[0], ['Marketings', 'Finances', 'Inventories']);
```